What are the conditions for two light sources to be "coherent"?
The sources must have a constant phase relation; a constant phase difference to be more specific. The sources having the same frequency is a natural consequence of this, if phase difference is considered to be constant wrt time and not position.
However, if the phase difference is to a constant, wrt to both time and position, then same wavelength is also a natural consequence.
So, in short, " Two light sources are said to be coherent iff they have a constant phase difference between them, wrt time"?? Or is it something altogether different. Explanation in beginners' terms would be very helpful as I am not from a pure Physics background.[I've attached a supporting image, an answer I found acceptable on Quora]

In communications or radar engineering a more general definition is also common: two sources, $A_1\cos(\omega_1 t +\phi_1(t)$ and $A_2\cos(\omega_2 t +\phi_2(t)$ are coherent if the phase difference between them $\psi(t)= (\omega_2-\omega_1) t +\phi_2(t)-\phi_1(t)$  as measured at any fixed point in space is a known function of time.

This assumes that the two waves are aligned. If one of the waves is coming in at an angle, you might get constant phase difference for different wavevectors for different spots on the detector (but the frequencies must still be the same; this rules out the basic linear dispersion curves).

coherence level between signals quantitatively is already defined, check Higher order coherence.

The "engineering" definition does not assume anything about having the two waves "aligned", presumably meant to signify that are moving in the same direction (parallel wave vectors). One wave could even represent the local oscillator beating the received signal in a mixer placed in a cavity with two incoming waves hitting it. In fact, this application is the original reason for this definition although it applies to more general cases, as well, such as to multipath propagation (random reflections with Doppler shifts) in which waves may be coming from any and all angles.

what's the question? You state a definition of coherence and then ask "what is coherence", which is a question for which you provided an answer. Obviously, you want something a little different, so what is that?

@JEB I meant "does coherence simply refer to the fact that the phase difference must be a constant?" In which case the frequency as well as the wavelength are same as natural consequences. Or does coherence mean "phase difference being a constant, only wrt time?" In which case, only the frequency needs to be same; coherence wouldn't be destroyed even if the wavelengths are different.

@naturallyInconsistent,  so does this mean that coherence refers to the phase difference being a constant wrt time, not necessarily wrt position. Thus 2 sources with same frequency but possibly different wavelengths may be considered to be coherent? If so, Thank you for the clarification. If I wasn't able to grasp your meaning, please take the pains to correct me.

@hyportnex so does this mean that coherence refers to the phase difference being a constant wrt time, not necessarily wrt position. Thus 2 sources with same frequency but possibly different wavelengths may be considered to be coherent? If so, Thank you for the clarification. If I wasn't able to grasp your meaning, please take the pains to correct me.

it is not that the phase difference stay constant but that the phase difference dependence on time is known as it evolves in time. Think of a moving mirror of known velocity off which a wave is reflected. You know what happens to the reflected wave, its frequency changes per the the Doppler shift, so it is known to  you as its phase deviates relative to the "reference" wave. If the velocity is unknown to you then you can use the evolution of the phase difference in time to measure that velocity: the Doppler radar.
